# Softkeyboard overlap Editext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, overlapping

The question - Why softkeyboard overlaps the Edittext ( as shown in the below image) has been asked several times at SO.

[image]

I have come across two answers

1. Add ScrollView as the top container and in fact it solves the problem but in my case it create another problems.
2. Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or adjustPan or several combination and that does not work.

**My Question**

Is there any other solution to solve this problem?

Also I am frustrated as to why this happens at all, should not framework take care of this.

Comment: what should happen in your opinion? as a matter of fact, windowSoftInputMode is exactly the solution for that problem. there is just so much space on the screen, and when you open the keyboard, something needs be hidden instead... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: @SimonSays You completely missed my point. In the image you can see that EditText is partially hidden and it will adjust itself once you start typing.

Comment: Define `layout_height="wrap_content"` not use "match_parent" in root View in your xml file will solve this `overlap on EditText` problem.